# Jenkins: Maven project with modules that won't be build: no pom.xml found

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, pom.xml

I've got 3 maven projects.
Project A defines B and C as module in it's pom.xml

Now I want to use Jenkins.
I defined to checkout/build project A and I think I have to manually checkout/build B and C as well, right?

The project didn't find the pom.xml of the other projects.
I defined them with relative path.

It works fine on my local machine, but it crashes on Jenkins:

```
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find de.saenger:xyz:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Now ... how to let the projects knowing each other?

Comment: please post the relevant parts of your poms, your project structure and the jenkins configuration

Answer (score 0):

Run `mvn build` on parent pom. It will build modules automatically.
You're running `mvn build` on module and mvn searches your local repository for parent pom to resolve dependencies but can't find the pom because you haven't built it yet.